# Create a new log thread or use a daemon thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I am a new programmer towards multi-thread, now I want to use a thread to write to a log file **for every 2 seconds**, I have two solutions but I don't know which one is better.

First:

```
def logger(msg):
    if msg != None:
      logging.info(msg)

def main():
  last = time.time()
  while True:
    msg = get_msg_from_somewhere()
    current = time.time()
    if current - last > 2:
      t1 = threading.Thread(target=logger, args = (msg, ))
      t1.start()
      last = current
```

Second:

```
message = None
def logger():
    global msg
    while True:
      if msg != None:
        logging.info(msg)
        msg = None
      time.sleep(2)

def main():
  t1 = threading.Thread(target=logger)
  t1.setDaemon(True)
  t1.start()
  while True:
    update_msg_from_somewhere()
```

**My thoughts:**

I prefer the second solution, because it doesn't need to compare the timestamp all the time and to create endless new threads (though they will be destroyed after they finish, right?), but I think the way I pass the `msg` is not the best (through global variables).

Do you have any ideas on how to pass variables to the daemon thread when it's running? And which solution do you prefer? Why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions.

The first one is using either daemon thread or not. It depends on your demand. If you can accept that the thread terminates suddenly which means there is no need for cleaning up, then you can use daemon thread as it will be convenient.

The second one is how to pass message in. As far as I think, this is a classic message queue problem. A better structure should be using a queue.

```
from queue import Queue

def logger(q):
    for msg in iter(q.get, None):
        logging.info(msg)

def main():
    q = Queue()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=logger, args=(q,))
    t1.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()
    while True:
        q.put(get_msg_from_somewhere())
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you mean by "If you can accept that the thread terminates suddenly which means there is no need for cleaning up", can you explain a little this?

Comment: @Jiahao A daemon thread will terminate if main thread terminate. While a non-daemon thread will keep running even if main thread terminate. So you will have no time to clean up your daemon thread if main thread terminate suddenly(For example, you press Ctrl+C). That will be dangerous as it may cause resource leakage or inconsistent state. But I think in your case, it doesn't matter.

Comment: But if I am writing logs to a file, then it will be better to create new threads, right? Like `with open('test.log', 'w') as log: log.write(msg)`

Comment: No, you should only open log file once in practice. Or better you should use `logging`'s file handler instead of manually write logs to file.

Comment: If I am using `loggin`'s file handler, do you think it's ok to use daemon thread?

Comment: Surely it is OK.